# Copy Node in XML to another position using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, element, xls

I try to replace a node if the value of it match with a node below.
For doing this i need an xls transformation script.

How can i copy a XML Part into another?

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>Peter</name>
    <surname>Muster</surname>
    <address>
      <object>addresses/address1</object>
    </address>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <surname>Muster</surname>
    <address>
      <object>addresses/address1</object>
    </address>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <address>
      <object>addresses/address3</object>
    </address>
  </person>
<persons>
<addresses>
  <address1>
    <street>road1</street>
    <zip>66666</zip>
    <town>Moonvillage</town>
  </address1>
  <address2>
    <street>road2</street>
    <zip>77777</zip>
    <town>Sunvillage</town>
  </address2>
  <address3>
    <street>road3</street>
    <zip>88888</zip>
    <town>Venusvillage</town>
  </address3>
</addresses>
```

The result XML have to be like this:

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>Peter</name>
    <surname>Muster</surname>
    <address>
      <street>road1</street>
      <zip>66666</zip>
      <town>Moonvillage</town>
    </address>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Lisa</name>
    <surname>Muster</surname>
    <address>
      <street>road1</street>
      <zip>66666</zip>
      <town>Moonvillage</town>
    </address>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>John</name>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    <address>
      <street>road3</street>
      <zip>88888</zip>
      <town>Venusvillage</town>
    </address>
  </person>
<persons>
```

It's not necessary to delete the addresses in the final xml.

At the moment i try it with a match on "object" and copy-of. but since now it is not working.

Comment: Which XSLT processor, XSLT version are you using? The use of an XPath expression like `addresses/address3` in the XML suggests you could benefit from XSLT 3's `xsl:evaluate`, like supported in Saxon 10 or Saxon-JS 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 and support for `xsl:evaluate` (i.e. Saxon 10 all editions, Saxon-JS 2, Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 commercial editions, Altova XMLSpy/Raptor) it might be solvable as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="person/address">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:evaluate xpath=". || '/*'" context-item="/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="addresses"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sounds great.. actually i work with version 2. So i need to check is it also possible using version 3.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Honnen's answer is better in the sense that it evaluates the XPath provided, but if you are limited to XSLT 1.0 you could try something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="addresses"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="address/object">
      <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="substring-after(.,'/')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//addresses/*[name()=$elemName]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiynew

Comment: Thanks for this alternative. If i can't  use version 3 it sounds for a good way to the target.